# Почему не запускается Open Server на Windows 10

Tags: openserver

Я скачал OS, распаковал, пытаюсь запустить и он просто не запускается, а при повторной попытке запуска пишет что он уже открыт

Comment: Так может он и открыт? localhost проверяли?

Comment: нет он закрыт, локалхост не работает

Comment: я так понял что там проблемы с совместимостью